# VB.Net Json Serialization Format

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, json, serialization

I was hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction in regards to the format of a Json.

I've never really worked with Json's and Serialization before so it's all a little new.

I need to return a Json from .Net in the following format.

```
[[Date.UTC(2011,12,14,8), 8], [Date.UTC(2011,12,14,9), 1]]
```

I'm almost there but am struggling with the format of my string, as by default the string is quoted. This is what I have:

```
        Dim oSerializerDt As New JavaScriptSerializer()

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Count", GetType(Integer))

        objresults.GetResults(id, period)

        Dim listResults As New List(Of Object())

        Dim newDate As String
        For Each result As Application.NewResults In objresults
            newDate = "Date.UTC(" + result.EventDate.Year.ToString + "," + result.EventDate.Month.ToString + "," + result.EventDate.Day.ToString + "," + result.EventDate.Hour.ToString + ")"
            listResults.Add({newDate, result.Count})
        Next

        Return oSerializerDt.Serialize(listResults)
```

This returns me the Json as follows, which is perfect other than the double quotes wrapping around the time string.

```
[["Date.UTC(2011,12,14,8)",8],["Date.UTC(2011,12,14,9)",11]]
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to how I can alter my code so the strings are formatted correctly I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out the Newtonsoft JSON serializer? It might help.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had a little play with the  Newtonsoft serializer but still can't seem to get my JSON in the required format. Is this something you know can be done with it? Any ideas on other approaches that would enable me to return in that format via Ajax?

Comment: Clutching at straws... have you tried changing your List(Of Object) to List(Of String)?

Comment: Yeah tried that but as expected it then wraps the integer in quotes as well.

Comment: Is there ever a case when you do want the double quotes in the string? If not then you could do replace on " before you return the final string. I know I'm not fixing the source of the problem but if it lets you get on with what you need to do...

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq with StringBuilder like this:

```
    Dim query = db.Employees.Select(Function(q) New With {q.EmployeeID, q.LastName}).ToList()
    Dim json As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For Each rows In query
    sb.Append(rows.LastName)
    Next
    Dim strjson As String = json.Serialize(Convert.ToString(sb))
    Response.Write(strjson)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't valid JSON ('Date' outside of quotes - see spec at http://www.json.org), so you can't really use a JSON serializer to do that. What you probably need to do is to go for some simple string manipulation:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable 
dt.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(String)) 
dt.Columns.Add("Count", GetType(Integer)) 

objresults.GetResults(id, period) 

Dim listResults As New List(Of String)

Dim newDate As String 
For Each result As Application.NewResults In objresults 
    newDate = "Date.UTC(" + result.EventDate.Year.ToString + "," + result.EventDate.Month.ToString + "," + result.EventDate.Day.ToString + "," + result.EventDate.Hour.ToString + ")" 
    listResults.Add(String.Format("[{0}, {1}]", newDate, result.Count)
Next

Return "[" + String.Join(", ", listResults) + "]"
```